# asp.net checkbox onclick event is not firing

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, internet-explorer-11

I have a webpage contains drop down and check box, after selecting the value in drop down the focus is next set to check box. when try to select the check box click event is not firing. click anywhere else on the page then am able to select the check box and this is happening only in I.E.-11 version.
Why cant we do select the check box when the focus is set on it ?
Any solutions or work around for this issue.?

Thanks in advance,
Shilpa

Comment: where is your code ? can you please put your code here ?

Comment: Why would a checkbox require focus? how else would you "check" the checkbox if you didn't click it? pressing enter? pressing enter may cause a postback depending on default controls etc.

Comment: Dear, please give more details about your problem and always put your code and what you have tried to resolve the problem (if any) in the question

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I just tested on IE11 and it works fine. onchange and OnClientClick did not work, onclick did:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="EnabledCheckBox" runat="server" OnClick="showDiv(this.checked);"/>
<div id="ShowDiv">Show me now</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showDiv(show) {
  if (show) {
    $('#ShowDiv').show("slow");
  } else {
    $('#ShowDiv').hide("slow");
  }
}
```